# Remove time from DateTime sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime, datetime-format

I need  date part from datetime. in format of "dd-mm-yyyy"

I have tried follwoing

**Query:**

`select Convert(varchar(11), getdate(),101)`

**Output:**

`01/11/2011`

**Query**

`SELECT cast(floor(cast(GETDATE() as float)) as datetime)`

**Output**

`2011-01-11 00:00:00.000`

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),DATENAME(DD,GETDATE())) + '-' + 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())) + '-' + 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),DATENAME(YYYY,GETDATE())) `
```

**Output:**

`11-1-2011`  i.e. "d-m-yyyy"

I required output in "dd-mm-yyyy" format.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),105)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 105)
```

More [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1145).

Answer (score 4):

Here you can find some examples how to do this: http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2009/1/9/Useful-tips-and-tricks-for-dealing-with-datetime-in-SQL

Answer (score 3):

Using the CONVERT function "works" but only if you're comparing strings with strings. To compare dates effectively, you really need to keep the SMALLDATETIME data type strongly typed on both side of the equation (ie "="). Therefore 'apros' comment above is really the best answer here because the blog mentioned has the right formulas to use to strip off the time component by "flattening" it to midnight (ie 12:00:00) via rounding and any date column in SQL Server 2005 will always default to 12:00:00 if the date is given without a time.

This worked for me ...

```
select dateadd(day, datediff(day, '20000101', @date), '20000101')
```